# Max limit on number of input in vs code java

Tags: java, input, user-input, visual-studio-code

I am trying some algorithm which requires large no of input samples for testing but at a time I cannot take input more than certain number of times.

```java
N = sc.nextInt();
...
int[] arr = new int[N];

for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
  arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
}

for(int elem: arr){
  System.out.println(elem+" "); 
}
```

Input format is

```
N 
//HERE GOES ARRAY ELEMENTS
```

where N- no of element in array

I'm using this user input [test_case_1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ayXET85FsCjQUJa6TDSVd7MA0OangykB/view?usp=sharing), but I can only input fraction of the given values.
I wanted to know what is restricting the number of input in vscode

Comment: How are you reading in this file in your code ?
Are you getting an error message or something ? 
Which exact steps are you trying to take and what result are you getting ?

Comment: I'm just manually inputting the values by pasting it. After pasting the values, it just enters part of it after which I can only delete but not input extra values

Answer (score 1):

Usually, using a scanner is perfectly alright. But with input samples of up to 90 000, which seems to be test case 1, it might be very slow due to excessive flushing.

Something like this might be more effective:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("temp_code_input.txt"));
...
int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
...
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
/* 
Assumes every input is on the same line. If not, create a new StingTokenizer
for each new line of input.
*/
int[] arr = new int[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
}

for (int elem : arr) {
  System.out.println(elem)
}
```

Comment: Thanks man for answering! I wanted to know if there is some inherent limit on the no of input that can be given manually. And if there is can we increase it.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just manually inputting the values by pasting it

It would be easier for you to just read this input from a file with the `Scanner` class.

```
      String s = Files.readString("PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE", StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

      // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

      // find the next int token and print it
      // loop for the whole scanner
      while (scanner.hasNext()) {

         // if the next is a int, print found and the int
         if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            //Store the data here ...
         }
         // if no int is found, print "Not Found:" and the token
         System.out.println("Not Found :" + scanner.next());
      }
```

Comment: I know how to take input from files. And my question is not that. I'm simply asking what is the reason for limit on number of input. And if there is any way I can increase this limit in vscode. And do let me know the reason for downvote if you did it

Answer (score 0):

When i test the input you provided, it stops and not accept more numbers when i paste them, so i ask in github: [Limit max number of terminal input](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136405) then get the reply:

> when I paste your example input into the terminal, it succeeds
> (although takes quite awhile) - what you might be seeing is the output
> (pasted text) trimmed relative to what you're expecting because of the
> maximum terminal scrollback which can be configured with
> `terminal.integrated.scrollback`

So please waiting because it would succeed that pasting the input. Enlarge the value of `terminal.integrated.scrollback` in Settings.json to check the output.